# Gradle with JavaFX: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I'm relatively new (about 1 month) to JavaFX, and even newer to Gradle. My project is [here, on Github](https://github.com/alinbadila/evisu). When I run `./gradlew build`, it works fine. But, when I run `./gradlew run` , I get all this:

```
Alins-MacBook-Pro:evisu Alin$ ./gradlew run
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:cssToBin SKIPPED
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:run
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1323468230.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: inputStream is null.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2429)
    at ro.badilos.evisu.EviSU.loadMainPane(EviSU.java:43)
    at ro.badilos.evisu.EviSU.start(EviSU.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$54/2140593657.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/186276003.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/1714838540.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/237061348.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application ro.badilos.evisu.EviSU
:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.74 secs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is this the base of all the problems?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: inputStream is null.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2429)
    at ro.badilos.evisu.EviSU.loadMainPane(EviSU.java:43)
    at ro.badilos.evisu.EviSU.start(EviSU.java:27)
```

What would be the correct path to the .fxml files?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the URL used for loading the FXML files? Also, add the original location of the FXML files in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `NullPointerException` is the root cause of the whole problem. You red resources incorrectly. Please replace this line (in class `ro.badilos.evisu.EviSU`:

```
Pane mainPane = (Pane) loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream(VistaNavigator.MAIN));
```

with the following one:

```
Pane mainPane = (Pane) loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(VistaNavigator.MAIN));
```

And change the following lines in `ro.badilos.evisu.VistaNavigator`:

```
public static final String MAIN    = "src/main/resources/Main.fxml";
public static final String VISTA_1 = "src/main/resources/NewSU.fxml";
public static final String VISTA_2 = "src/main/resources/NewSMURD.fxml";
```

to:

```
public static final String MAIN    = "Main.fxml";
public static final String VISTA_1 = "NewSU.fxml";
public static final String VISTA_2 = "NewSMURD.fxml";
```

After introducing these changes all resources will be read correctly. Running `gradle clean run` still results in exception but this is another one.

To fix the *new* exception change (in `ro.badilos.evisu.VistaNavigator`):

```
public static void loadVista(String fxml) {
    try {
        mainController.setVista(
            (Node) FXMLLoader.load(
                VistaNavigator.class.getResource(
                    fxml
                )
            ));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

to:

```
public static void loadVista(String fxml) {
    try {
        mainController.setVista(
            (Node) FXMLLoader.load(
                VistaNavigator.class.getClassLoader().getResource(
                    fxml
                )
            ));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Remember to always refer to resources via `ClassLoader`. Now it runs, however another NPE is printed to console.

**EDIT**

Ok, the final NPE is cause by:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    try {
        Image focIcon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("pool/foc16px.png"));
        btnNewSU.setGraphic(new ImageView(focIcon));

        Image smurdIcon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("pool/smurd16px.png"));
        btnNewSMURD.setGraphic(new ImageView(smurdIcon));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    try {
        Image focIcon = new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("foc16px.png"));
        btnNewSU.setGraphic(new ImageView(focIcon));

        Image smurdIcon = new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("smurd16px.png"));
        btnNewSMURD.setGraphic(new ImageView(smurdIcon));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the last thing, you need to fix the reference to `Nomeclator.db` in `ro.badilos.controller.InfoSituatiaProdusaController` as well.

Comment: @badilos, if it was helpful, please [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)